# Octave keeps giving results from function although not asked

Tags: function, output, octave

I created a function in Octave for which I, at this moment, only want one of the possible outputs displayed. The code:

```
function [pi, time, numiter] = PageRank(pi0,H,v,n,alpha,epsilon);
  rowsumvector=ones(1,n)*H';
  nonzerorows=find(rowsumvector);
  zerorows=setdiff(1:n,nonzerorows); l=length(zerorows);
  a=sparse(zerorows,ones(l,1),ones(l,1),n,1);

  k=0;
  residual=1;
  pi=pi0;
  tic;

  while (residual >= epsilon)
      prevpi=pi;
      k=k+1;
      pi=alpha*pi*H + (alpha*(pi*a)+1-alpha)*v;
      residual = norm(pi-prevpi,1);
  end

  pi;  
  numiter=k
  time=toc;

endfunction
```

Now I only want numiter returned, but it keeps giving me back pi as well, no matter whether I delete `pi;`, or not.

It returns it in the following format:

```
>> PageRank(pi0,H,v,length(H),0.9,epsilon)
numiter =  32
ans =

   0.026867   0.157753   0.026867   0.133573   0.315385
```

To me it seems strange that the pi is not given with its variable, but merely as an `ans`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the [Octave documentation for this](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Calling-Functions.html) is not very extensive, but perhaps it gives enough hints to understand that how you think about output variables is wrong.

The call

```
PageRank(pi0,H,v,length(H),0.9,epsilon)
```

returns a single output argument, it is equivalent to

```
ans = PageRank(pi0,H,v,length(H),0.9,epsilon)
```

`ans` is always the implied output argument if none is explicitly given. `ans` will be assigned the value of `pi`, the first output argument of your function. The variable `pi`  (nor `time,` nor `numiter`) in your workspace will be modified or assigned to. These are the names of local variables inside your function.

To obtain other output variables, do this:

```
[out1,out2,out3] = PageRank(pi0,H,v,length(H),0.9,epsilon)
```

Now, the variable `out1` will be assigned the value that `pi` had inside your function. `out2` will contain the value of `time`, and `out3` the value of `numiter`,

If you don't want the first two output arguments, and only want the third one, do this:

```
[~,~,out3] = PageRank(pi0,H,v,length(H),0.9,epsilon)
```

The `~` indicates to Octave that you want to ignore that output argument.